# Kafka Connect JDBC Sink Connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to write data from a topic (json data) into a MySql Database.  I believe I want a JDBC Sink Connector.

How do I configure the connector to map the json data in the topic to how to insert data into the database.

The only documentation I can find is this.

> "The sink connector requires knowledge of schemas, so you should use a
>   suitable converter e.g. the Avro converter that comes with Schema
>   Registry, or the JSON converter with schemas enabled. Kafka record
>   keys if present can be primitive types or a Connect struct, and the
>   record value must be a Connect struct. Fields being selected from
>   Connect structs must be of primitive types. If the data in the topic
>   is not of a compatible format, implementing a custom Converter may be
>   necessary."

But how do you configure?  Any examples?

Comment: have a look at this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPT3X_4.2.5/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.admin.doc/doc/admin_kafka_jdbc_sink.html and http://blog.magiclyde.me/post/export-data-from-kafka-topics-to-mysql-with-jdbc-sink-connector

Comment: @SRJ, so the key of json field needs to match a column name in the db table?

Comment: Yes, as per your schema. Check here for example https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html#produce-a-record-in-sqlite

Comment: @SRJ, so I assume that means you need to use Confluent Schema Registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume that means you need to use Confluent Schema Registry?

For "better" schema support, then yes. But no, it is not required.

You can use the JsonConverter with `schemas.enable=true`

Your JSON messages will need to look like this though,

```
{
   "schema" : {
      ... data that describes the payload
   }, 
   "payload": {
      ... your actual data
   }
}
```

For reference to this format, you can see [this blog](https://rmoff.net/2017/09/06/kafka-connect-jsondeserializer-with-schemas.enable-requires-schema-and-payload-fields/)

You can use Kafka Streams [or KSQL](https://gist.github.com/rmoff/165b05e4554c41719b71f1a47ee7b113) to more easily convert "schemaless" JSON to a schema-d Avro payload

Comment: It is also possible to create you own Converter to create Record with Schema , and register it like other Kafka Connects plugins (Connectors, Transform).

Comment: @wardziniak Is there a transform that you know of that can add in a `schema.literal`, let's say to describe a "raw" JSON payload?

Comment: @wardziniak K. Guess I'll add a JIRA when I get around to it